# Validating substrings are equal

Tags: java, substring, tdd

I am trying to take a string and validate the final digit to the rest of the string. I have made two substrings. for the first substring you have to times each char by its position add it to a count and then do modulus 11 of the result of the whole count. This should then equal the second substring. I am working with TDD and I am getting an error that the results are not equal when they should be. I am unsure why and any help would be great.

Here is my error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlWPQ.png)

Here is my method:

```
 public boolean checkEndingDigit(String s) {
    String endingCharacter = s.substring(s.length()-1);
    String startingCharacters = s.substring(0, s.length()-2);
    int startingCharSum = 0;
    boolean result = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-2; i++) {

        if (Character.isDigit(startingCharacters.charAt(i))) {
            startingCharSum = Character.getNumericValue(startingCharacters.charAt(i) * i);
            System.out.println(startingCharSum);
        }
    }

    int endingCharSum = Character.getNumericValue(endingCharacter.charAt(0));
    int finalStartingCharSum = startingCharSum % 11;


    System.out.println(finalStartingCharSum);
    System.out.println(endingCharSum);

    if (finalStartingCharSum == endingCharSum) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void checkValidEndingDigit() {
    boolean result = validator.checkEndingDigit("0471958692");
    assertTrue(result);
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After looking over and testing possible issues, I believe the issue is as simple in the for loop declaration

Since you are indexing startingCharacters, and startingCharacters is 2 less than s in size, you should also take that into account when iterating through it. My change SHOULD resolve this

```
public boolean checkEndingDigit(String s) {
    String endingCharacter = s.substring(s.length()-1);
    String startingCharacters = s.substring(0, s.length()-2);
    int startingCharSum = 0;
    boolean result = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-2; i++) {

        if (Character.isDigit(startingCharacters.charAt(i))) {
            startingCharSum = Character.getNumericValue(startingCharacters.charAt(i) * i);
        }
    }

    int finalStartingCharSum = startingCharSum % 11;
    int endingCharSum = Character.getNumericValue(endingCharacter.charAt(0));

    if (finalStartingCharSum == endingCharSum) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Or, I suppose you could just use startingCharacters.length() instead of s.length()

Comment: Hi, this fixed my issue and I recently solved it, but now for a correct string my test is now failing. I am getting -1 for the finalStartingCharSum and 2 for the endingCharSum when I know they should both be equal. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

startingCharacters is shorter than s, therefore i goes to far.

```
for (... i < s.length() ...)
startingCharacters = s.substring(...);
startingCharacters.charAt(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a couple things wrong.

First for the following:

```
String startingCharacters = s.substring(0, s.length()-2);
```

you should change the  -2 to -1.  This will ignore all but the last character which I presume is your check digit.

And you need to change this

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
```

to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < startingCharacters.length(); i++) {
```

And finally, you are not summing anything. Just assigning. And move the `i` outside of the `getNumericValue` method.

```
startingCharSum = Character.getNumericValue(startingCharacters.charAt(i) * i);
```

However most of the above could just be replaced with the following using the original string by simply iterating one less than the length and starting at 1 instead of 0 (multiplying by 0 will always result in 0 so why do it?).

```
startingCharSum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < s.length()-1; i++) {
     startingCharSum += Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)) * i;
}
```

Also I get false when I run this.

And note that when you multiply by the position, you are always multiplying by 0 at the first position.  If that is correct, you can always start your loop at 1 since the product of the first digit will always be 0.

Comment: Hi, I changed this whilst going through it myself but still manage to get 2 for ending and 9 for the first digits. But I am not sure why as I was given strings that are right such as "0471958692" and "0471606958". It seems to be going better now and I am not getting -1 as an answer but am still not getting equals which I should be?

Comment: Should both of those return true?

Comment: yes they should both return true, but I am unsure what I am missing

Comment: They both work for me and return true.  Did you read all my comments in my answer?

Comment: I just saw another problem and updated my answer.  You need to move the `i` outside of your `Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i) * i);`   You need to get the numeric value **before** mutlplying.

Comment: I was going to say I implemented all you did and still did not get the answer, after moving the i out the brackets I have now got the test to pass! Thank you so much!